# Apache POI's FormulaEvaluator doesn't work after modifying a Cell's formula

Tags: java, excel, groovy, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to write to a spreadsheet some test case expectations...

These expectations, as of right now, are all in the form of string cell values. They contain some expected dollar amounts...

Here's example row:

| Member ID | NPI Number | Member Prefix | Member First Name | Member Last Name | Member Suffix | Payment Frequency (A, M, S, Q) | Is Child Member? | Expected Fee | Expected Frequency Discount | Expected Family Discount | Expected Net Amount | Expected Gross Installment | Expected Net Installment | Test Case Step 2 Passed? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 139 | 1209360364 |  | Main07-28-2023 01:28:49 | RandomMember |  | A | true | $ 2,362.00 | $ 326.00 | $ 116.91 | $1,919.09 | $ 2,362.00 | $ 1,919.09 | true |

I make sure that the dollar amounts have the *Accounting Number Format*.

I did notice a need to **have Excel calculate an Expected Net Amount** (one cell minus the sum of some others), instead of my code, by entering in a formula like:

```
=I34-(J34+K34)
```

This works in the spreadsheet: after hitting enter, the value is calculated. However, when I try to read it programmatically, I face some issue:

The util method:

```
    public static double GetDollarAmount(Cell cell) { 
        switch (cell.getCellType()) { 
            case CellType.NUMERIC.code:
                return cell.getNumericCellValue();
            case CellType.STRING.code:
                return SMDNumberUtils.parseDouble(cell.getStringCellValue());
            case CellType.FORMULA.code:
                return cell.getSheet().getWorkbook()
                    .getCreationHelper()
                    .createFormulaEvaluator()
                    .evaluate(cell)
                    .getNumberValue();
                    
            default: 
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cell Type ${cell.getCellTypeEnum().name} not yet supported!")
        }
    }
```

fails for the formula-type cell, because it returns 0 instead of, in the case of that example row, 1919.09 . When I check the `CellValue` that the `evaluate()` call returns, I see a `CellValue` with `#VALUE!` (which typically gets thrown when you're tryna use a numeric formula on string values)

Even when I try to tweak my code to re-write the formula, by wrapping "VALUE()" around any cell references:

```
    public static double GetDollarAmount(Cell cell) { 
        switch (cell.getCellType()) { 
            case CellType.NUMERIC.code:
                return cell.getNumericCellValue();
            case CellType.STRING.code:
                return SMDNumberUtils.parseDouble(cell.getStringCellValue());
            case CellType.FORMULA.code:
                
                FormulaEvaluator evaluator = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook()
                    .getCreationHelper()
                    .createFormulaEvaluator();
            
                CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
                    
                if (!cellValue.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.ERROR))
                    return cellValue.getNumberValue();
                    
                cell.setCellFormula(cell.getCellFormula()
                    .replaceAll(/[A-Z]+\d+/, { match ->
                        return "VALUE($match)"
                    }))
                
                return evaluator.evaluate(cell)
                    .getNumberValue();
                    
            default: 
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cell Type ${cell.getCellTypeEnum().name} not yet supported!")
        }
    }
```

It still fails, with the same issue! Nothing changes, except we have a safe formula for next run!

**How can I fix this**, given that my testing framework, Katalon Studio, has me stuck on Apache POI **v3.17** ?

Comment: Is the last calculated value of use to you? You could always read that for formula cells instead of re-evaluating the formula

Comment: The value that was calculated when the Excel file was open is of use to me...

Comment: Call https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCachedFormulaResultType-- to see the cached type, then fetch the value based on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem, with some tweaking of the code:

```
public static double GetDollarAmount(Cell cell) { 
    switch (cell.getCellType()) { 
        case CellType.NUMERIC.code:
            return cell.getNumericCellValue();
        case CellType.STRING.code:
            return SMDNumberUtils.parseDouble(cell.getStringCellValue());
        case CellType.FORMULA.code:
            CellValue cellValue = this.EvaluateCellFormula(cell);
                
            if (!cellValue.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.ERROR))
                return cellValue.getNumberValue();
                
            cell.setCellFormula(cell.getCellFormula()
                .replaceAll(/[A-Z]+\d+/, { match ->
                    return "VALUE($match)"
                }))
            
            return this.EvaluateCellFormula(cell)
                .getNumberValue();
                
        default: 
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cell Type ${cell.getCellTypeEnum().name} not yet supported!")
    }
}

public static CellValue EvaluateCellFormula(Cell cell) { 
    return cell.getSheet().getWorkbook()
            .getCreationHelper()
            .createFormulaEvaluator()
            .evaluate(cell)
```

It looks like we need new `FormulaEvaluator` every time we `evaluate()`...

Comment: `FormulaEvaluator` is normally workbook-scoped, you should be fine to re-use it with the same excel file, but you'll need a new one for each file

Comment: In this case, I needed it just to re-evaluate a formula cell in the same sheet...!